# PS4 Controller Not Working Anymore

Tags: controllers, ps4

I was playing the night before. When I went to sleep I turned it off as usual. But this morning I went to play and the controller won't turn on. The light won't blink or turn on at all. I tried plugging it in and it still didnt work. Wont charge, no light, nothing.

Comment: How old is it?  Sometimes batteries just won't take a charge anymore.  Did you try leaving it plugged in for a few hours to see if it was just too low?

Comment: Have you tried using a different charger?

Comment: There is a small hole in the back of the controller that is a reset button. Try inserting something in there until you feel the button press. This probably won't fix it as it should have run out of battery by now, but it is worth a shot.